# How to show that, $ \mathrm{CH}_k (X) \otimes_{ \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{Q} \simeq \Omega_k (X) \otimes_{ \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{Q} $?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy, cobordism, chow-groups

Let $ X $ be a $ n $ - dimentional oriented closed real manifold ( i.e : compact and without boundary ).

Can you tell me how to show that,
$$ \mathrm{CH}_k (X) \otimes_{ \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{Q} \simeq \Omega_k (X) \otimes_{ \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{Q} $$ where,
$ \mathrm{CH}_k ( X ) $ is the Chow group that is the free abelian group on the set of real $ k $ - submanifolds $ Z \subset X $ of $ X $, with $ 0 \leq k \leq n $, modulo rational equivalence, and, $ \Omega_k (X) $ is the oriented bordism group defined as the set of all isomorphism classes of $ k $ - manifolds $ M \to X $ modulo bordism, where $ M \to X $ is bordant to $ N \to X $ if there is a $ W $ with $ \partial W = M - N $. ( Here, $ M - N $ denotes the disjoint union of $ M $ and $ N $ with the orientation of $ N $ reversed ).

Here, I would like to point out that, the oriented bordism group $ \Omega_k (X) $ is the one which is isomorphic to $ MSO_k (X) := \displaystyle \lim_ {\longrightarrow \\ \ \ k} \pi_{n + k} (MSO(k) \wedge X_+) $ if I'm not mistaken, and should not be confused with the unoriented bordism group $ \mathfrak {M} _k (X) $ which is isomorphic to $ MO_k(X) := \displaystyle \lim_{\longrightarrow \\ \ \ k} \pi_ {n + k} (MO(k) \wedge X_+) $.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is false. For $k=0$, your $CH_0(X)$ is enormous, but $\Omega _0(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ (if $X$ is connected).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If it is possible, can you correct me what i'm wrote from the beginning, because, in the book of M. Levine, and F. Morel, intiteled algebraic cobordism, page, $ 136 $, comparison with chow groups, the authors says that, $ \mathrm{CH}_* (X) \simeq \Omega_* (X) \otimes_{ \mathbb{L} } \mathbb{Z} $ if $ X $ is a smooth of quasi-projective $ k $ - scheme. What is the difference ?. Thank you.

Comment: @abx, When you say that $ \mathrm{CH}_0 (X) $ is enormous, i think that $ \Omega_0 (X) $ is also enormous. Isn't it right ?

Comment: What is the notion of rational equivalance for real submanifolds? I only know the definition for subvarieties.

Comment: @Will Sawin : Sorry, i mean algebraic real submanifolds. Take a look here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_manifold

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't checked the book by Levine and Morel, but there is a short arXiv article by Levine at https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0304206.pdf.  There he writes $\mathbb{L}$ for the Lazard ring, which is the same as $MU_*$, and is polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$ on countably many generators.  There is a natural map $\Omega_*(X)\otimes_{\mathbb{L}}\mathbb{Z}\to CH_*(X)$, and Levine's Theorem 5.13 says that this becomes an isomorphism after tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$.  It is important here that we are tensoring over $\mathbb{L}$; as $\mathbb{Z}$ is much smaller than $\mathbb{L}$, we find that $\Omega_*(X)\otimes_{\mathbb{L}}\mathbb{Z}$ is much smaller than $\Omega_*(X)$, consistent with the fact that $CH_*(X)$ is also fairly small.  Note also that the claim is an isomorphism of graded rings and relies on the graded tensor product; there is no natural formulation that gives $CH_k(X)$ for a single value of $k$.

Levine's article only gives a brief indication of a proof of Theorem 5.13; I'm afraid I can't help you with that.  In the analogous topological situation, however, we can just recall that $(E_*X)\otimes\mathbb{Q}=H_*(X;\mathbb{Q})\otimes E_*$ for all spectra $E$ and $X$.  This gives $MU_*(X)\otimes\mathbb{Q}=H_*(X;\mathbb{Q})\otimes\mathbb{L}$ and so $(MU_*(X)\otimes_{\mathbb{L}}\mathbb{Z})\otimes\mathbb{Q}=H_*(X;\mathbb{Q})$.